# How to convert yyyymmdd hhmmss Etc/GMT to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

I have this date format in a string column-

yyyymmdd hhmmss Etc/GMT  (for example - 20211022 173124 Etc/GMT)

How can I convert it to this date format? yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss (2021-11-22T17:31:24)

I can't use the original report for uploading data for spesific system. the only format should be "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has 2 functions: [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse string to date and [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to output in your desired format.
For your case it can be something like this:

```
select date_format(str_to_date('20211022 173124 Etc/GMT', '%Y%m%d %H%i%S'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S');
```